# Переопределить метод ToString для класса

Tags: c#

У меня есть матрица, в которой диагональ заполнена единичками. Вот мой код:

```
int[,] arr;
public Matrix()
{
    arr = new int[3, 3];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            if (j == i)
                arr[i, j] = 1;
            else
                arr[i, j] = 0;
        }
    }        
}

public Matrix(int[,] arr)
{
    this.arr = arr;
}
```

Мне нужно написать метод `GetLength` (аналогичный методу `arr.GetLength()`) и метод `ToString`.

Как мне переопределить `ToString()`, возвращающий строковое представление  матрицы, чтобы матрица выводилась по столбцам и строкам?

Comment: Пока не описана конкретная проблема, можно только посоветовать https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-override-the-tostring-method

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы.

Comment: Приведите а) код вашей матрицы б) пример входных и выходных данных.

Comment: Эм. Ну если у вас в матрице заполнена диагональ, то вывод будет одинаковый как при обходе "сначала строки, потом столбцы", так и при обходе "сначала столбцы, потом строки". Но в принципе, вопрос я понял, могу написать ответ.

Comment: Буду очень благодарен за помощь

Answer (score 6):

Мы будем работать со следующими двумя классами (слегка причесал ваш код):

```
public abstract class Matrix
{
    protected Matrix(int size)
    {
        this.Size = size;
        this.Arr = new int[size, size];
    }

    // Показывает матрицу обходя сначала строки, потом столбцы
    public void ShowRowFirst()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < this.Size; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < this.Size; j++)
            {
                Console.Write($"{this.Arr[i, j]} ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }

    // Показывает матрицу обходя сначала столбцы, потом строки
    public void ShowColFirst()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < this.Size; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < this.Size; j++)
            {
                Console.Write($"{this.Arr[j, i]} ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }

    public int GetLength()
    {
        return this.Size * this.Size;
    }

    // TODO: Тут в последствии мы будем переопределять ToString

    protected int Size { get; set; }

    protected int[,] Arr { get; set; }
}

public class DiagMatrix : Matrix
{
    public DiagMatrix(int size)
    : base(size)
    {
        this.FillDiag();
    }

    private void FillDiag()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < this.Size; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < this.Size; j++)
            {
                if (j == i)
                    this.Arr[i, j] = 1;
                else
                    this.Arr[i, j] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Сама программа:

```
void Main()
{
    var matrix = new DiagMatrix(3);

    matrix.ShowRowFirst();
    Console.WriteLine();

    matrix.ShowColFirst();
    Console.WriteLine();

    matrix.ToString();
    Console.WriteLine();

    Console.WriteLine($"matrix length: {matrix.GetLength()}");
}
```

Теперь собственно о вашей задаче ("переопределить метод `.ToString()`").

Каждый класс в c# является потомком класса System.Object, в котором есть метод string ToString():

```
namespace System
{
    public class Object
    {
        // ...

        public virtual string ToString()
        {
            return this.GetType().ToString();
        }

        // ...
    }
}
```

И мы можем поступить двумя способами: либо через ключевое слово override, либо через ключевое слово new.

Мы можем оставить сигнатуру метода (входные и выходные параметры) такими же, как были раньше:

```
    // переопределяем .ToString() - вариант 1
    public override string ToString()
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < this.Size; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < this.Size; j++)
            {
                sb.Append($"{this.Arr[j, i]} ");
            }

            sb.AppendLine();
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

Либо мы можем поменять и входные-выходные параметры, например, можем сказать, что на выходе будет void, а не string:

```
// переопределяем .ToString() - вариант 2
public new void ToString()
{
    this.ShowColFirst();
}
```

Разница в вариантах. Ключевое слово new скрывает метод базового класса (в том числе и виртуальный), а override переопределяет виртуальный метод базового класса.

> А можно сделать ToString() с параметрами - например, указывать -
>   выводить по столбцам или по колонкам? Такой пример был бы интереснее.

```
// более универсальный метод вывода - перегрузка не требуется
public void ToString(bool showColFirst = true)
{
    if(showColFirst)
        this.ShowColFirst();
    else
        this.ShowRowFirst();
}
```

Comment: А можно сделать `ToString()`  с параметрами - например, указывать  - выводить по столбцам или по колонкам? Такой пример был бы интереснее.

Comment: @MBo Можно конечно, только тут нельзя будет говорить о перегрузке - в базовом классе нет функции на входе принимающей bool или enum. Это просто будет новая функция, без всяких new и override.

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь , в классе по заданию запрещено вводить значения массива , в main в конструктор передавать только массив , который уже константный , спасибо ещё раз помогли

Comment: @ДмитрийТерещенко Ну и прекрасно. Я специально писал код не совсем такой, чтобы не была готовая домашка. Немного подумать место есть - допишете себе так, как требуется.

Comment: A.K большое спасибо за помощь